# Received rep twice for the same edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing, suggested-edits

I suggested one edit to a post, but when it was approved I received rep for it twice. I know there's some sort of autmated rep cleanup done regularly (nightly?), but I'm not sure if this is a known issue covered by that or not.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, give it 24 hours for the accounting to sort itself out of whatever put it there. If it remains and it still bothers you, this will probably be better explained / fixed at [meta.se]. Honestly, though, it's just 2 rep - I know at the beginning every little bit counts, but still.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I'm not too concerned about it w/ regards to my rep total, just figured a bug's a bug (low priority as it may be)

Comment: Yeah, and it's a curious enough find as is. Probably still with a better shot in [meta.se], though - just give it a bit to see if it sticks.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty It's fine to just report bugs on child metas, no need to repost on MSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look at the post links there. :)

You proposed two edits - one on the question and one on an answer. They happened to be approved within seconds of each other.

Comment: *facepalm* Can't believe I forgot I edited both. And also didn't catch the issue for multiple days.

Comment: @SnoringFrog It's all good. :)